# How can I duplicate what NSFetchedResultsController is doing while monitoring Core Data?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios5, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a model that does some work with core data, and I currently use a NSFetchedResultsController to get notified when something changes in core data.  I'm not driving a UITableView from this, and the API for the fetched results controller is a little awkward.  I want to replace it with something easier.  My question is this, how is the NSFetchedResultsController listening to changes in Core Data, and how can I duplicate it behind a nicer API?  I'm using iOS 5+

Answer (score 3):

It looks like, at the very least, [you can get notifications from your MOC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html) like these:

```
Core Data uses these string constants as keys in the user info dictionary in aNSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification notification.

NSString * const NSInsertedObjectsKey;
NSString * const NSUpdatedObjectsKey;
NSString * const NSDeletedObjectsKey;
NSString * const NSRefreshedObjectsKey;
NSString * const NSInvalidatedObjectsKey;
NSString * const NSInvalidatedAllObjectsKey;
```

As an approach, maybe you can start by stubbing a complete protocol you wish Apple had given us, then adding implementations and little tests as you need them.